# Bulk Data Insertion that includes relationships

Tags: apex, batch, csv, insert

Good day everyone,

I just want to ask your idea in regards with my problem. I am trying to read a data from csv and upload the data to salesforce. Below is an image of sample data in my csv.

This is the sample scenario :

In every row there are fields that will be save in account and contact(contact must be related to the account). At the moment, I am using batch to save the data because there are lots of it.

I am thinking that it is easier to insert the data one at a time. First is insert the account and then get the inserted Id and use it for contact insertion.But if I will do this, there maybe possibility that I will hit some salesforce limit.

But if will create a List for Account object and List for Contact Object It would be hard to get the Account Id .

I just want to ask suggestion of what is the better way to save the data. Please help.

Thank you.

[image: Sample csv data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the concept of `External ID` works.

Go through following post: [How do I use an External ID to import related records?](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000002783&language=en_US)

You need to create external Ids in both objects and each related Contact should have same external Id its parent Account has. During import map the external Id to match the record. It will automatically set up the correct relationship.

Import Account first then Contact.